# Get the first part of the innertext

Tags: linq-to-xml

This is what I got:

```
<xml>I need this text<notthistext>blahblah<notthistext></xml>
```

How can I get:
I need this text

I am using .value and it is returning the text for everything like this: 
I need this textblahblah

Answer (score 0):

In python it would be: `somexml.firstChild.firstChild.data` or `somexml.getElementsByTagName('xml').firstChild[0].data`

Answer (score 0):

This is actually for linq

The trick was to get all the nodes under the element and just reference the first node using the First function rather then using value